# Should clock signals be pipelined across super logic regions?

Tags: fpga, clock

I am deploying an FPGA design that will take up resources across 3 separate super logic regions (SLRs). However, I've it is having trouble passing timing. The reports from Vivado show that the clock signal propagation across the SLR boundary is taking up approximately 30% of the total timing delay on my max-delay paths. I know that logic components can be pipelined so that the pipeline stage falls across the SLR crossing - can the same techniques be applied to clock signals? If not, are the paths outside of the primary SLR doomed to have a 30-40% timing overhead?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try inserting BUFGs into the clock signals on the secondary SLRs.

Comment: @JonathanS. Will Vivado recognize that the output of the BUFG is a clock signal? Do I need to do anything in particular inside the TCL script or design constraint files?

Comment: I'm unfortunately not quite sure about this. It's possible that BUFGs alone will not solve this problem entirely, but they're definitely a part of the solution - without them, you get clock skew everywhere. You might have to use clock synthesizer / PLL blocks to ensure the correct phase relationship between the clocks on the SLRs. You might also just need more pipeline stages around the SLR crossing.

Comment: In my experience, simply pipelining the SLR data interface will work.  You will need to compartmentalize the logic into 3 separate entities such that you can just get data across the boundary.

Comment: @JonathanS. This is exactly what I ended up doing. I think I had some bad module->slr mappings that created some problems but otherwise, I just manually assigned modules to SLRs and had FIFO queues go across the boundaries with BUFGs buffering the clock signals on the secondary SLRs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @johnnymopo Thank you for your help as well!